# Aligning money numbers to the left bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi im having trouble with some money number alignment. I want my data do be aligned to the left side of the columns BUT the numbers of the money have to look relative to each other like in the screenshot.

This screenshot is what I have atm:

[image]

This is what I want to do:

[image]

Here is my structure:

```
<tr> 
  <td style="text-align: left">name</td>
  <td style="text-align: right">money</td>
  <td style="text-align: center">date</td>
</tr>
```

And the only css atm that I use for positioning is setting the widht of every of those td's to 30%

At first I thought I could position them simply by putting a `<p>` in there that would align the content to the right and give the rest its relative widht, however that way would be possible but then I get a ball of js or jquery that I prefer not to have.

I have bootstrap installed but as of now I havent really touched it in this project except for the column grid positioning.

Does anyone have some kind of way to achieve what I am trying, or can someone push me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

ADDITION: Semi complete code sample:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdgqmZ?editors=1100)

The above code is the whole section the table is located in but I copied all css relative to the issue and not every single css class my problem is reconstructed there exactly even the random `<p>` tag I tried is in there.

Comment: Yes, and the outer table and what the table is contained in

Comment: that will take me a sec, but will do right now.

Comment: @ZimSystem not all the css for some of the outher tags are there but I copied the code and the css to the point i reconstructed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two columns:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">List of money values</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">[Empty]</div>
</div>
```

And align text to right in the first one:

```
<p class="text-right">Your text.</p>
```

Comment: So, inside of my <td> i should open a row and do that O.o? I know it would give me something along the lines I asked but I thought I should not open divs etc in a table?

Comment: Ok, if you're using tables (you used the tag bootstrap) you should create two columns (<td>), first with the content aligned to the right and the second empty. Give width -50% or whatever you wawnt- to both so that they are width fixed, mainly for the second one that is empty.

Comment: Ah ok and then give the header colspan right? (used the bootstrap tag becouse the containter etc is bootstrap thought it was relevant.)

Comment: `<td align="right">` the atributte colspan is to make the column span in multiple (not used in your case)

Comment: Ah oke. Ill try to work this out now ill let you know if I get it to work

Comment: Well i just realised that this wont be the solution, i need to do something inside the td to fix this. if i simply create a second td to fix this it will create even bigger problems

Comment: Other option is to add `margin-right: [pixelsfromright]px` in a new class for all tds if you want to have the space avoiding another column

Comment: Hmm I tried it and that does actually kind of work, I will need to fiddle arround with some media screen's for responsivenes but for the main layout this works. thanks a lot :)